# multidimensional arrays with __set() and __get()

Tags: php, methods, multidimensional-array, magic-methods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using __set with arrays solved, but why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310473/using-set-with-arrays-solved-but-why)

Is it possible to set multidimensional arrays with PHPs magic `__set()` and `__get()` methods? i.e `$Foo->arrayKey['anotherKey']='newValue';` would set `$foo->_data['arrayKey']['anotherKey']=='newValue';`

```
//example setting values to $_data[$k]
class Foo
{
   private $_data=array();

   public function __set($k, $v)
   {
       $this->_data[$k]=$v;
   }

   public function __set($k)
   {
       return $this->_data[$k];
   }
}
```

Comment: Return a reference from the `__get` function onto the subarray. Direct interception of key access of that $_data array isn't possible.

Comment: not a duplicate since he is asking why but it does answer my question. and thanks ill upvote when I can...gotta wait 5 min

Comment: +1 what mario says, additionally you could returm an object with [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/ArrayAccess). But what mario suggested as duplicate looks very fitting to me as well.